# Implement search on all values of CNContact object

Tags: iphone, swift2, ios9, uisearchcontroller

I want to implement search on all contacts fetched on a table view using ios9, CNContacts framework. I can search through GivenName, FamilyName etc, but want to search through phone numbers and emails as well when a user enters a search query in search bar. Just as we can search phone numbers/emails in ios9 Apple contacts.

I know, since phonenumbers/emailsaddresses are array of tuples, it is not possible to do it using NSPredicate format string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you could do

```
func findAllEmails () {
    let fetch = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactEmailAddressesKey])
    fetch.keysToFetch = [CNContactEmailAddressesKey] // Enter the keys for the values you want to fetch here
    fetch.unifyResults = true
    fetch.predicate = nil // Set this to nil will give you all Contacts
    do {
        _ = try contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetch, usingBlock: {
            contact, cursor in
            // Do something with the result...for example put it in an array of CNContacts as shown below
            let theContact = contact as CNContact

            self.myContacts.append(theContact)

        })

    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }

    self.readContacts() // Run the function to do something with the values
}

func readContacts () {
    print(myContacts.count)
    for el in myContacts {
        for ele in el.emailAddresses {
          // At this point you have only the email Addresses from all your contacts - now you can do your search, put it in an TableView or whatever you want to do.... 
            print(ele.value)
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure this code can be optimized ;) I just made it quick...
I tested this solution only with Emails but it should work as well with Phone Numbers. It is up to you what you do with the retrieved values. This might be only a workaround but as you said, you can't do it with a NSPredicate.

Comment: This worked for me. Re optimization, you don't have to set fetch.keysToFetch. It is already set by the previous statement. Also, you don't need to cast contact to CNContact, it already is one. And, you can use a trailing closure to make the code just look cleaner.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for your suggestions. By the time I will update the answer...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am also awaiting Apple's response. Let's see if they have an optimized way.

Comment: what is `contactStore` and `myContacts` initialized as? @ArminScheithauer